# Angular not displaying the value that I am setting in controller in template html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I am rather new to angularjs  and I have been still using jquery ajax calls in my controllers.  Yes I will eventually switch over, but this is my problem:

My Success:

```
success: function (data) {
    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
    console.log(json);  // This correctly loops over EACH record and spits out the total record count,  thus the variable "json" indeed is called multiple time and logging to chrome debugger just fine
            $scope.commentResult = json;  // TRYING to just set this variable each time this $.ajax function is called within the success section 
            //angular.element('#commentCount').text(json);  // my attempt to set a span id text to the variable holding the value
        },....
```

I thought that setting this scope value should display just fine

```
$scope.commentResult = json;
```

But it is not showing up

HTML page I call a function and pass a changing value   tip.id
    {{setCommentCount(tip.id)}}

I then attempt to have it be set from the controller -- ajax call above

```
<span id="commentCount">Total Count: {{commentResult}}</span>
```

Am I not doing this correctly?

Because I have another place on the page in which this similar type of thing i am doing

```
{{setTipId(tip.id)}}
```

That function call correctly passes in the ever changing tip.id in the loop

Then I have $scope.detailFrame   get set

```
 ng-src="{{detailFrame}}"
```

So it worked for that other element with ng-src  ...

Showing a bit more html and js code

http://plnkr.co/edit/9PC3edazTsltk546RG4Z?p=catalogue

Comment: Can you post a plnkr please

Comment: Please update your question with your HTML page also completely instead of that specific line.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/9PC3edazTsltk546RG4Z?p=catalogue

Comment: The plnkr is not databound ,  but at least you can see some of html and the controller js   parts that are important

Comment: Where you injected `ng-app` and `ng-controller` directives ? I didn't found them in the HTML page you posted.

Comment: well, there is just too much code to put it into plnk.

Answer (score 0):

if `commentResult` is in json format, do something in template like

```
{{ commentResult | json }}
```

In the success function kik a digest cycle yourself

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.commentResult = json;
})
```

Comment: It is not in json format  sorry, that is bad variable name left over from other code.    json = 13  ,   json = 10  ,   always just a number ...

Comment: How do I call it  , just wrap it in a function?

Comment: 1. json is not defined , and chrome debugger is in an endless loop

Answer (score 0):

Call `$scope.$apply()` in success callback after assigning var to update watchers.
And do not use jquery ajax in angular controller it is bad practice .Use $http service and promises instead. Have a look for documentation of $http service .

[here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: $scope.$apply()   is changing every single record and alternating the numbers and is in an never-ending loop!    :(

Comment: so I gather i cannot use $scope.apply in jquery ajax?